# Set values in log4j properties file programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

I have a log4j properties file. on application start up i need to set value for one of the property. is it possible? because i know the value for the property on application start up only.

```
log4j.properties
----------------

Environment = ${env}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is java Application or web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -DEnvironment=dev <YourMainProgram>
```

then in log file you can call that variable as

```
log4j.appender.logfile.File=appname-${Environment}.log
```

**Edit:**

**Tomcat:**  If application is running in Tomcat you can define environment in Catalina.bat.

Open the "**Catalina.bat**" file placed in the "bin" directory.

```
 set CATALINA_OPTS=" -DEnvironment=dev"
```

Then Restart your server by Catalina.bat.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you can do that by specifying the JVM arg in your application startup and use the same in your log4j file as in the below example:
where env is a JVM arg.

log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=D:/bpd/${env}Userlog.log

Comment: Thanks for ur reply? where can i set JVM args? is it possible to set them permanently? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using eclipse then in the run configuration you set as -Denv=someValue or if running in command prompt then set as java -Denv=someValue yourApplication.

Comment: It is a web application. i am deploying war in tomcat. here where can i set? Please help me?

Comment: @user1016403 : Edited the answer please check.